# Error "CS0104: 'DataType' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType' and 'CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.DataType"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error:

> "CS0104: 'DataType' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType' and
>   'CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.DataType'"

while running an ASP.NET 4.0 application. Can any one help me on this issue?

Comment: You need to remove the ambiguity and fully qualify one of the names to resolve the type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described in the documentation on [Compiler Error CS0104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0104) you've got a symbol clash - there are two classes in scope of your source file which are both called `DataType` - one is in the [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces) `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and the other is in the namespace `CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.DataType'`.

You need to do one of the following to resolve this:

**1.** Explicitly provide the full namespace prefix on each usage, i.e.
`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType` and `CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.DataType`:

```
var cdt = new CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.DataType();
var sdt = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType();
```

**OR 2.**  Or use a [using directive to alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) the namespaces / types, e.g.

```
using SystemDT = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Carlos = CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter;
```

And then then identify the types with the namespace aliases, e.g..

```
var dt = new Carlos.DataType();
```

**OR 3.** You can also alias at the class level:

```
using SystemDataType = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType;
using CarlosDataType = CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.DataType;
...
var myObj = new CarlosDataType();
```

**OR 4.** If you don't need to symbols from both namespaces, then delete the unused namespace from the `using` clause.

My preference would be for Option 2 - it makes it clearer to the reader that there is a namespace clash, without being too verbose (like Option 1 is)

**Edit**

> Re: "I tried by giving full prefix but still I am getting error "CS0138: A
> using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces;
> 'CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.DataType' is a type not a namespace"

(All relating to point #2, above). The error message refers to a situation like this, which isn't permitted in .Net (but is permitted in Java imports)

```
// i.e. This won't work, can't import at a class level unless it is aliased
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType;
```

As per my answer, I would recommend that you alias the namespace, and then use the alias prefix to disambiguate between the 2 `DataType`s

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution I used was to delete all using and make the references again. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I forgot, in my case, I had this problem when defining the controller route.